# Запуск двух разных контейнеров

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Подскажите, можно ли из одного docker-compose собрать 2 разных контейнреа:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  my-container:
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME}
    environment:
       - DOCKER_COMMAND=${DOCKER_COMMAND}
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: deployments/Dockerfile
```

И запустить одновременно. Т.е. в одном случае я запускаю:

```
DOCKER_COMMAND=run CONTAINER_NAME=c1 docker-compose up my-container
```

После него запускаю:

```
DOCKER_COMMAND=test CONTAINER_NAME=c2 docker-compose up my-container
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы они оба работали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через docker-compose так сделать нельзя.

Если посмотреть ману `docker-compose up --help`, то

> If there are existing containers for a service, and the service's configuration
> or image was changed after the container's creation, `docker-compose up` picks
> up the changes by stopping and recreating the containers (preserving mounted
> volumes). To prevent Compose from picking up changes, use the `--no-recreate`
> flag.

Тут однозначно написано, что если сервис существует, то он пересоздается с новыми параметрами, а прошлые контейнеры останавливаются.

Я проверил, при старте второго первый завершается с кодом 137. Если для второго вызова использовать флаг `--no-recreate`, то команда фактически ничего не делает, и аттачится к первому контейнеру.

Вывод: так сделать нельзя, кроме дублирования сервиса в docker-compose.yml или запуска через `docker run ... (параметры присоединения в сеть docker-compose, монтирование томов, etc)`.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ выше не совсем верен можно использовать

```
docker-compose -p ProjectName up -d
```

Это позволит запустить с одного файла конфигурации запустить 2 контейнера, остаются только конфликты на уровне портов и имен.